# ¿Cómo implementar un botón para cargar más contenido con la directiva ngInfiniteScroll de AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lo que quiero hacer es que aparezca un botón **solamente** cuando el tamaño del navegador no deje mostrar el scroll, así puedo ejecutar la función de cargar más contenido mediante el botón y luego de que ya haya suficiente contenido para mostrar el scroll que desaparezca para ejecutar la función normalmente con el scroll.

```js
app.controller( 'newsCtrl', [ '$scope','$rootScope','DataSource',
    function($scope,$rootScope,DataSource){ DataSource.get('../json/news.json',
        function(data){
            $scope.itemData = data.slice(0,18);
            $scope.itemsData = data;
            $scope.selected = data[0];
        }
    );
    $scope.loadMore = function(){
      if($scope.itemData === undefined || $scope.itemsData === undefined){
        return;
      }
      var last = $scope.itemData.length-1;
      for(var i=1; i<=18; i++){
        if($scope.itemData.length >= $scope.itemsData.length){
          break;
        }
        $scope.itemData.push($scope.itemsData[last+i]);
      }
    };
  }]).factory('DataSource', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
      get: function(fileName,callback){
        $http.get(fileName).then(function(response){
          callback(response.data);
        },function(){
          console.log('error');
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: En la página oficial hay un ejemplo que usa a Reddit en formato JSON, tal vez te pueda servir.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo he editado la pregunta, tal vez ahora puedes ayudarme.

Comment: @toledano he editado la pregunta, tal vez ahora puedes ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Por qué es que quieres que la cantidad este sujeta al tamaño de la pantalla? Osea, la cantidad de "artículos" que entran en pantalla depende no solo del tamaño de la pantalla, sino también a las dimensiones de cada uno de los "artículos", puede que algunos sean mas altos que otros; o PEOR aun, el usuario haga "zoom" en el navegador y se las dimensiones asumidas se verán distorsionadas. En resumen, nunca sabrás a ciencia cierta, cuan alto puede ser un "articulo" a no se que inicialmente crees uno y hagas los cálculos correspondientes.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo tienes razón, no lo avía pensado. ¿Sabes cómo hacer que aparezca un botón para cargar los artículos sólo cuando el espacio del navegador sea muy grande para mostrar el scroll, creo que así sería una buena idea, no? o mejor aún que los artículos carguen sólo mediante el botón y no el scroll.

Comment: Creo que una buena solución que podrías implementar es detectar la plataforma (desktop|tablet|mobile) y en base a esto paginar, **por ejemplo**, de a 50 si es desktop, 25 si es tablet y 15 si es mobile (ya que se supone que la conexión es mas lenta y el envió de datos cuesta $).